# Javascript - Creating a series of <a> tags within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a series of anchor tags that increment by 1 within the wunderNav div.

When I run this loop with console.log(counter); It gives me a nice list 1 - XX. When I try to add the anchor tags it only appends the last of the series.

```
for(var counter = 1; counter <= thisGM.grids.length; counter++){
    document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML = '<a id="wunderNumber'+ counter +'" href="javascript:thisGM.goToGridPage('+ counter + ');">' + counter + '</a>';
}
```

Thanks everyone, fairly new to javascript and I was smashing my head against the wall!

Here is what I needed:

```
 for(var counter = 1; counter <= thisGM.grids.length; counter++){
    document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML += '<a id="wunderNumber'+ counter +'" href="javascript:thisGM.goToGridPage('+ counter + ');">' + counter + '</a>';}
```

Comment: Try using += instead of = when setting innerHTML. Using = will reset the innerHTML every single time, thus giving you only the last entry of the loop.

Comment: @Bucky24 exactly, `document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML =` should be `document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML +=` make sure to reset it before the loop.

Comment: document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML **+**= whatever, what you are doing is overriding the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning to `.innerHTML` literally replaces the contents of that node. You need to APPEND, e.g.

```
var w = document.getElementById('wunderNav');
for(...) {
   w.innerHTML += '<a ....></a>';
               ^^-- string concatenation
}
```

As well, note that the HTML you have in your code snippet is invalid. You start with an `<a>`, but end with a `</span>`

Comment: While this may be right, you might want to suggest setting `innerHTML` **once**, by building the big HTML string in the loop, and then setting `innerHTML` after the loop. Or more cleanly by using DOM methods

Answer (score 1):

You are wiping away the contents of the `wunderNav` every iteration of the loop.  Use `+=` instead of just `=` to append to the current `innerHTML` of the div.

```
document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML += '<a id="wunderNumber'+ counter 
    +'" href="javascript:thisGM.goToGridPage('+ counter + ');">' 
    + counter + '</span>';}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it instead in every loop cycle:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('wunderNav');
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + '<a id="wunderNumber'+ counter +'" href="javascript:thisGM.goToGridPage('+ counter + ');">' + counter + '</a>';}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var counter = 1; counter <= thisGM.grids.length; counter++){
  document.getElementById('wunderNav').innerHTML += '<a id="wunderNumber'+ counter +'" href="javascript:thisGM.goToGridPage('+ counter + ');">' + counter + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var counter = 1; counter <= thisGM.grids.length; counter++){

    document.... += '<a id="wunder....">' + counter + '</span>';

}
```

Use `+=` insted of `=`. This is because you need to join every anchor tag to the previous one.

Good luck